# Magento CE to Magento GO?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-go

I got a question.

Is it possible to upgrade my Magento CE to Magento GO?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be possible, but afaik is the registration to magento go closed? Beside this many features you have with your own instance you don't have with go.

Comment: Magento Go is closed now, so the question becomes irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento GO is a hosted and managed Magento service.

Any modifications you have made to your Magento CE ecommerce site that cannot be replicated through the GO administrative panels or not available in the GO app store will not be able to be used in GO. You will also lose any template package you are using that isn't available in GO.

The idea was that you would not need to deal with hosting and by limiting modification to only what is allowed, you gain dependability. Less features, more uptime, cheaper price.